# Clipping a raster DEM between two elevations

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, clip

I am trying to clip a raster DEM between two elevations, specifically a portion of the contiguous United States in an SRTM 90m DEM.

I would like to create a vector polygon mask that overlies the all parts of the DEM that lie between two elevations; for example, between 1000m and 2000m.

At the moment I have downloaded the SRTM section I need in both ASCII and GeoTIFF formats. I am using QGIS 2.18.15.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do too much in one step. Why not reclassify to  1=1000-2000m, else=nodata and then convert to vector.  It's unclear why you would need to download two versions of the same dataset.

Answer (score 5):

You want **Raster Calculator**. Reclassify your raster as follows:

```
("elevation@1"  < 1000)* 1 + (("elevation@1" >= 1000) AND ("elevation@1" < 2000)) * 2  + ("elevation@1"  >=2000)* 1
```

Convert the output raster to polygon. Select by expression all features with the value 1 and delete. Remaining features will indicate areas in the desired elevation range.